# I have multiple unequally sized rows that I want to combine into a single matrix. How can this be done?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

As stated by the title, I have various rows which do not contain equal amounts of data. Furthermore, the size of each row changes per user input on another sheet. I want to combine all these rows into a single row or column without gaps (doesn't matter which). The order does not matter. I need something very efficient as I have 200 rows.

[This handy formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44128/how-to-specify-the-entire-sheet-as-range-in-google-sheets) retrieves the data from an entire sheet. "code_f3" is the name of the sheet whence the data is retrieved. I applied FLATTEN to it, and it did what I wanted except for filter out the blanks. How can I get rid of the blanks?

```
=FLATTEN(ArrayFormula(
  INDIRECT(
    "code_f3!"
    &ADDRESS(1,1,,TRUE)
    &":"
    &ADDRESS(ROWS(code_f3!A:A),COLUMNS(code_f3!1:1),,TRUE)
    ,
    TRUE
  )
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something as simple as `=tocol(code_f3!A1:ZZZ,1)` to put all the results (minus blanks) into a single column. ZZZ is the maximum number of columns Google Sheets allows (18278).